# Get editor's OldValue from DevExpress RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit in EditValueChanged event

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I'm using the classic WinForms version of the DevExpress XtraEditors. The WPF version makes it easy to get the editor's old value in the **EditValueChanged** event, but I don't see how to get the old value in the WinForms counterpart `EditValueChanged` event.  If it can be obtained from within that event, how to do it?

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_EditValueChangedtopic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit` class is not an editor itself. This class is only holding properties for in-place editors. So, to get editor's old value you must get the editor itself (from `sender` object) and use its [`BaseEdit.OldEditValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_OldEditValuetopic) property.
Here is example:

```cs
private void repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var baseEdit = (BaseEdit)sender;

    if (baseEdit.OldEditValue.ToString() == "Some value")
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: In the version I have (2010.1) although the cast to BaseEdit succeeds, `OldEditValue` returns null, but it should be returning the value that is being replaced. If you would confirm that it is working properly and cite the version you're using, I can accept your answer.

Comment: @Tim My version is 14.1.5 and I tested the code before I posted it here. It is working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the version info.